# Как получить список из функции всплывающего окна?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Есть главное окно `Rep_Orders()` на нем кнопки "**`Select Cols`**" и "**`Download`**". 
Кнопка "**`Select Cols`**" выводит окно с списком колонок и `CheckBox` для выбора колонок. Также в этом окне есть две кнопки "Clear" для очистки всех `CheckBox` и "Select" для получения списка выбранных колонок (функция `get_columns()` возвращает "`cols_list`").

Далее этот список нужно передать в функцию `dowload_Orders()`, которая уже по выбранным колонкам сформирует отчет.

У меня не получается это сделать. Список колонок печатается только в функции `get_columns()` и далее не передается.

Помогите решить проблему передачи списка колонок `cols_list` в функцию `dowload_Orders()`.

Всплывающее окно "report_cols_ui.py":

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(308, 407)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.columns_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        self.columns_list.setObjectName("columns_list")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.columns_list, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.btn_select = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.btn_select.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 30))
        self.btn_select.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icon/icon/check-circle.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_select.setIcon(icon)
        self.btn_select.setObjectName("btn_select")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_select)
        self.btn_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.btn_clear.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 30))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icon/icon/trash-2.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_clear.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName("btn_clear")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_clear)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Columns"))
        self.btn_select.setText(_translate("Form", "Select"))
        self.btn_clear.setText(_translate("Form", "Clear"))
from wind import resource_rc
```

Файл с функциями "order.py":

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QWidget, QListWidgetItem
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError

from db import db, engine
from models import Base_PL, Brands, Contracts, Customers_ALL, Orders, PL_chng, Packs, Products, Stock
from wind.pages.orders_ui import Ui_Form as Ord_Form
from wind.pages.report_cols_ui import Ui_Form as Cols_Form

class Rep_Orders(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rep_Orders, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ord_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.ui.btn_select_cols.setToolTip('выбери колонки для отчета')
        self.ui.btn_select_cols.clicked.connect(self.go_to_Select_Cols)

        self.ui.btn_download.clicked.connect(self.dowload_Orders)
        
        self.ui.rep_date.setCalendarPopup(True)

       
    def go_to_Select_Cols(self):
        self.columns_form = QWidget()
        self.columns = Cols_Form()
        self.columns.setupUi(self.columns_form)
        
        orders_db = self.get_all_Orders_from_db()
        if orders_db.empty == False:
            orders_db = orders_db[sorted(orders_db.columns )]
            cols = orders_db.columns.values.tolist()
            
            for col in cols:
                item = QListWidgetItem(col)
                item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                self.columns.columns_list.addItem(item)
            self.columns.btn_clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_cols_list)
        
        self.columns_form.show()
        self.columns.btn_select.clicked.connect(self.get_columns)


    def clear_cols_list(self):
        for i in range(self.columns.columns_list.count()):
            item = self.columns.columns_list.item(i)
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            
        
    def get_columns(self):
        cols_list = []
        for i in range(self.columns.columns_list.count()):
            item = self.columns.columns_list.item(i)
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                item = item.text()
                cols_list.append(item)
        self.columns_form.close()
        
        return cols_list

   
    def dowload_Orders(self):
        order_data = self.get_all_Orders_from_db()
        order_data = order_data[cols_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы получать быстрые и правильные ответы,
вы должны научиться составлять **`МИНИМАЛЬНО-ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ`** пример,
который демонстрирует проблему, а не надеяться на чей-то свежий взгляд.

Возможное решение вашей задачи, выглядит примерно так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(308, 407)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.columns_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        self.columns_list.setObjectName("columns_list")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.columns_list, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.btn_select = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.btn_select.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 30))
        self.btn_select.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icon/icon/check-circle.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_select.setIcon(icon)
        self.btn_select.setObjectName("btn_select")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_select)
        
        self.btn_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.btn_clear.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 30))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icon/icon/trash-2.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_clear.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName("btn_clear")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_clear)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Columns"))
        self.btn_select.setText(_translate("Form", "Select"))
        self.btn_clear.setText(_translate("Form", "Clear"))
#from wind import resource_rc


# +++
class WindowSelectCols(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowSelectCols, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.cols_list = []                                       # !!! +++
        cols = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',]
        
        for col in cols:
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(col)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.columns_list.addItem(item)
                
        self.btn_clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_cols_list)        
        self.btn_select.clicked.connect(self.get_columns)
      
    def get_columns(self):
        self.cols_list = []
        for i in range(self.columns_list.count()):
            item = self.columns_list.item(i)
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                item = item.text()
                self.cols_list.append(item)

        print(f'def get_columns():  {self.cols_list}')                   #
        self.hide()                                                      # +++
#-       return cols_list

    def clear_cols_list(self):
        for i in range(self.columns_list.count()):
            item = self.columns_list.item(i)
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        self.cols_list = []
        

class Rep_Orders(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rep_Orders, self).__init__()
        
        self.windowSelectCols = WindowSelectCols()                     # !!! +++
        
        self.btn_select_cols = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выбери колонки для отчета')
        self.btn_select_cols.setToolTip('Выбери колонки для отчета')
        self.btn_select_cols.clicked.connect(self.go_to_Select_Cols)        
        
        self.btn_download = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выполнить dowload_Orders')
        self.btn_download.clicked.connect(self.dowload_Orders)
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_select_cols)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_download)

    def go_to_Select_Cols(self):
        self.windowSelectCols.show()                                   # +++
        
    def dowload_Orders(self):
        if self.windowSelectCols.cols_list:                            # !!! +++
            print(       # ----------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--------
                f'Колонки для отчета: {self.windowSelectCols.cols_list}') 
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Вы не выбрали колонки для отчета.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Rep_Orders()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]